# Empathy is telling me I have a new IM message but I can't find it

Tags: 12.04, empathy

... and can't get the notification to go away:

[image: phantom nofication]

How do I find the message or clear the notification? I've looked at my list of contacts and none of them have a blinking icon. I've closed Empathy and the notification is still there when I open it. It's kind of annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to restart the machine today and the phantom message went away.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the Envelope icon in your toolbar (beside your system clock), under "Chat" you will see the message that it thinks still needs to be read.  Click on the message and the number should go away.